# How do I install Vivaldi beta 2 on Ubuntu 15.10?

Tags: 15.10

Using the .deb file results in the Ubuntu Software Center opening (just opening, not showing anything about Vivaldi, nor installing it) and the .rpm file opens in the built-in Archive Manager.

Answer (score 2):

In `software centre`, just click install on the right

[image]

If for some reason that is not working for you, run these commands to download and install Vivaldi beta 2

```
wget https://vivaldi.com/download/stable/vivaldi-beta_1.0.344.37-1_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i vivaldi-beta_1.0.344.37-1_amd64.deb
```

It works using the terminal commands on my Xubuntu 15.10.

Comment: Welcome to ask Ubuntu! As you are a new user, if this helped you, please click the check mark on the left to say thanks and allow others to find the correct answer.